# Multiple versions of Three.Js being imported?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm a bit clueless as to why I'm getting this error and what could possibly be going wrong? Here's a breakdown of what's happening:

1. I started up an NPM/webpack app
2. Then I imported in three js and three mesh line:

```
import * as THREE from "three";
import { OrbitControls } from "three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js";
import { MeshLine, MeshLineMaterial, MeshLineRaycast } from 'three.meshline';
```

I then started adding in lines and boxes and stuff.
3) This is an error that I keep getting:

> WARNING: Multiple instances of Three.js being imported.

4. To debug this I commented out the line of code for Meshline - which does get rid of this issue.
5. So I had a snoop around the MeshLine file and it looks like this:

```
var THREE = root.THREE || (has_require && require('three'))
  if (!THREE) throw new Error('MeshLine requires three.js')
```

6. My working theory is that its not multiple versions but multiple different times that its getting imported. and this is happening because I have something as THREE and as three.
7. Is this intuition right? And what do I do to fix it?

EDIT 1:
[image: Browser output]

I also tried to import the files in like so:

```
import {PerspectiveCamera, AmbientLight, DirectionalLight, WebGLRenderer, Color, Scene, sRGBEncoding} from "three";
```

But that didn't help either

EDIT 2:
Tried the `window.THREE = THREE;` that didn't work either

Also here is a repo that I have created that replicates this error :
https://github.com/range-et/THREE_THREEMESHLINE

Comment: Imports should be automatically deduplicated. What does the output look like in the browser? Is ThreeJS there more than once?

Comment: But your hunch may be correct. Why are you all-capsing the import? That's a bit nonstandard.

Comment: Im all capsing cause the documentation has written it up that way : https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Installation

Comment: Hi, interesting problem, can you at least show us more code? Can we see your `package.json` ?

Comment: Try setting `window.THREE = THREE;` in your `index.js`. If you get linter errors just have your linter ignore the line. Do this before any code that uses MeshLine

Comment: Reduce it to just importing a single thing from `three.js` and a single thing from `three.meshline`. Make sure you "use" the imports in your code (just `console.log` them) so they don't get optimized away. Then run your build server again to see if the error still exists. If not, check your browser console for error messages which may be more informative. Also try a normal build (sometimes the dev server can be finicky). If you still can't make headway, you may need to [log an issue against three.meshline](https://github.com/spite/THREE.MeshLine/issues) regarding webpack compatability.

Comment: Configure your bundler to pack `three` before `meshline`.

Comment: So I tried what @KitangaNday said and that didn't work either, GarciadelCastillo
and I tried what you said TheJim01 and made no headway. What seems to be the issue is that when webpack is compiling the code the meshline stuff is getting called before everything else. Ive made a repo replicating this on github

Comment: Try `console.log`ing `root.THREE` and see if it exists. One trick could be to set it in your html, at the bottom of your body tag. `<script>window.THREE = {}</script>`  or right before where your bundle export will be.

Comment: See also: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/17482#issuecomment-1054681673

mrdoob believes this is fixed (or fixable)